# Java System.getProperty("line.separator") not working in apache server

Tags: java, regex, string, char, system-properties

My method `System.getProperty("line.separator")` is not working in *Apache* server but seems to work in local *Eclipse*.

Actual implementation

```java
str2=str1.replace(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "CH(50)");
```

The code works in eclipse but not in server and "line.separator is not replaced by CH(50).

Comment: What OS are you running on the server? Is it the same as on your "eclipse" machine?

Comment: Is the client sending the line.separator that applies at the server? Is the line.separator present at all? Not a real question.

Answer (score 4):

***line.seperator*** : Sequence used by operating system to separate lines in text files

`System.getProperty("line.seperator")` is operating system dependent.

Your server may be Linux and you are testing it locally in windows